# How to handle server side event dispatching and handling in Java?

Tags: java, events, gwt

I'm working on a web based application which uses java servlets for RPC calls.

I'm looking for a good way of dispatching and handling events on the server. In a PHP application I'm familiar with using Symfony's EventDispatcher class for adding event listeners and dispatching events, but I'm having a hard time finding something comparable in Java as most stuff I can find is about dealing with UI events and I'm wanting to both listen for and fire events on the server.

I'd also like the actual event handling to happen asynchronously on a separate thread or something so that, for example, an API call to handle adding a payment can do what's necessary, fire and event, and return immediately, even though the event might trigger some more time intensive stuff like sending emails or contacting a partner to inform them of the new balance.

Would I be best off just implementing this myself using my own event interfaces, ExecutorService/Runnable and Observer or Publish/Subscribe patterns? Or are there existing libraries (or built in features I don't know about) for doing some of this for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried looking for existing libraries?

Comment: Yes, quite a lot.

The only one I've really found so far is Google's guava library, which might work. I was hoping some people might have some suggestions or know if there are any common ones people use.